# create-react-app is working only with cmd but not with bash. With bash : 'npx' not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: reactjs

I have node installed in my laptop, npm as well as nvm.

[image]

I can check node version, npm and nvm. But when I try to run the command: npx create-react-app file-name,
it says create-react-app is not recognized as an internal or external command. Even I tried using npm install -g create-react-app and then create-react-app  it gives the same type of error. I tried cleaning cache as well.

I have my project files installed in D drive whereas node is in C drive.

Any solutions in this case???
Please help me.

Comment: did you try reinstalling you node and npm?

Comment: A couple of times. But did not work.

Comment: hmm tried doing it as Administrator? could you upload the error in the command?

Comment: 'create-react-app' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Answer (score 0):

Try by adding path variable, here are steps:

1. Use the global Search Charm to search "Environment Variables".
2. Click "Edit environment variables for your account"
3. Click "Environment Variables" in the dialog.
4. In the "System Variables" box, search for Path and edit it to include C:\Program Files\nodejs (or path of node installaton). Make sure it is separated from any other paths by a ;
5. Click on apply and save the settings.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have path added as well. But still, it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

It is mainly a npm version issue, you may be using the older version of npm, if it is so, then try with these commands -

```
npm install -g create-react-app
```

and after that

```
create-react-app project-name
```

Else, you may upgrade the npm version to use your `npx` command

Hope this may be helpful to you.

Comment: All including node, npm, nvm are installed today and are the latest versions.

Comment: After 

npm install -g create-react-app
 it showed installed in roaming/npm/node_modules.
but I need my project files in D drive. how to access that

Comment: @bijay nothing to worry, just go in the D:/ directory and run command create-react-app project-name, the project will be setup in D drive

Comment: It didn't work. I reinstalled as well. But not working. Create-react-app is not recognized as an internal or external command